# Does it makes sense to manage Docker containers of a/few single hosts with Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, server, kubernetes

I'm using docker on a bare metal server. I'm pretty happy with docker-compose to configure and setup applications.

Still some features are missing, like configuration management and monitoring maybe there are other solutions to solve this issues but I'm a bit overwhelmed by the feature set of Kubernetes and can't judge if it would help me here.

I'm also open for recommendations to solve the requirements separately:

- Configuration / Secret management
- Monitoring of my docker hostes applications (e.g. having some kind of dashboard)
- Remot container control (SSH is okay with only one Server)
- Being ready to scale my environment (based on multiple different Dockerized applications) to more than one server in future - already thinking about networking/service discovery issues with a pure docker-compose setup

I'm sure Kubernetes covers some of these features, but I have the feeling that it's too much focused on Cloud platforms where Machines are created on the fly (since I only have at most few bare metal Servers)

I hope the questions scope is not too broad, else please use the comment section and help me to narrow down the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think the Kubernetes is absolutely much your requests and it is what you need.

Let's start one by one.

> I have the feeling that it's too much focused on Cloud platforms where Machines are created on the fly (since I only have at most few bare metal Servers)

No, it is not focused on Clouds. Kubernates can be installed almost on any bare-metal platform (include ARM) and have many [tools and instructions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/pick-right-solution/#bare-metal) which can help you to do it. Also, it is easy to deploy it on your local PC using [Minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube), which will prepare local cluster for you within VMs or right in your OS (only for Linux).

> Configuration / Secret management

Kubernates has a powerful configuration and management based on special objects which can be attached to your containers. You can read more about configuration management in [that](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/04/configuration-management-with-containers.html) article.

Moreover, some tools like [Helm](https://helm.sh) can provide you more automation and range of preconfigured applications, which you can install using a single command. And you can prepare your own [charts](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/charts.md) for it.

> Monitoring of my docker hostes applications (e.g. having some kind of dashboard)

Kubernetes has its own [dashboard](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/) where you can get many kinds of information: current applications status, configuration, statistics and many more. Also, Kubernetes has great integration with [Heapster](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster) which can be used with [Grafana](https://grafana.com) for powerful visualization of almost anything.

> Remot container control (SSH is okay with only one Server)

Kubernetes [controlling tool](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/) `kubectl` can get logs and connect to containers in the cluster without any problems. As an example, to connect a container "myapp" you just need to call `kubectl exec -it myapp sh`, and you will get `sh` session in the container. Also, you can connect to any application inside your cluster using `kubectl proxy` command, which will forward a port you need to your PC.

> Being ready to scale my environment (based on multiple different Dockerized applications) to more than one server in future - already thinking about networking/service discovery issues with a pure docker-compose setup

Kubernetes can be scaled up to thousands of nodes. Or can have only one. It is your choice. Independent of a cluster size, you will get production-grade networking, service discovery and load balancing.

So, do not afraid, just [try to use it locally](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/hello-minikube/) with Minikube. It will make many of operation tasks more simple, not more complex.

Comment: Okay that confirms what I hoped. But where to get started with only one production/demo server. Should I install Minukube there? Or how to make 1 Server the only Master & Node in my "cloud" (recommendation from the docs is to have three nodes, but I'm fine with just one for now, I do not need to keep a uptime SLA, yet)

Comment: If you are OK with one node - you can use Minikube with or without VMs, just do not forget to backup everything:) Actually, Minikube is just a small all-in-one installation of Kubernetes optimized for a fast start from scratch and inside it is a real Kubernetes with all features.

Comment: I found this, trying it right now on a Digital Ocean VM: https://medium.com/@Grigorkh/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-1ac2ef522a36